# ActiveMQ JMSXGroupId messages struck up in broker

Tags: java, caching, activemq-classic, consumer

I am using 3 network of ActiveMQ brokers in my application. To maintain the order in consuming messages i used JMSXGroupId. i have configured the network of brokers using the following configuration.

```
<managementContext>
          <managementContext 
              createConnector="false"/>      
</managementContext>

<networkConnector
    name="amq_cluster_amq1_to_amq2"
    uri="static:(tcp://host2.name:61616)"
    networkTTL="3"
    suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true">
</networkConnector>

<networkConnector
    name="amq_cluster_amq1_to_amq3"
    uri="static:(tcp://host3.name:61616)"
    networkTTL="3"
    suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true">
</networkConnector>
```

like this i have configured for all the 3 brokers, My policy entry is as follows

```
<policyEntry 
    queue=">" 
    producerFlowControl="false" 
    memoryLimit="5mb" 
    queuePrefetch="1">
```

I am having 3 consumers in 3 different JVM, the endpoints configured with concurrentConsumers=5. the broker URL for the consumers are configured as follows.

**Consumer-1 :**

```
failover:(tcp://host1.name:61616,
    tcp://host2.name:61616,
    tcp://host3.name:61616)
        ?randomize=false
        &priorityBackup=true
```

**Consumer-2 :**

```
failover:(tcp://host2.name:61616,
    tcp://host3.name:61616,
    tcp://host1.name:61616)
        ?randomize=false
        &priorityBackup=true
```

**Consumer-3 :**

```
failover:(tcp://host3.name:61616,
    tcp://host1.name:61616,
    tcp://host2.name:61616)
        ?randomize=false
        &priorityBackup=true
```

**Use Case:**
I use to publish 3000 messages every 15 mins. for each and every message the JMSXGroupId is different & unique one. The last 2 messages will have the same JMSXGroupId.

**Issue:**
In consumer side the ~95% of messages consumed properly and ~5% of messages will struck up in broker (Pending in broker).

**Note:**

1. The consumer will take 1000ms to process the message.
2. Messages will start to be in broker in the 4th or 5th iteration of message publish.

If we increase the **maxPageSize** from default value 200 to 1000. then the struck up starts @12th or 15th iteration.

Could any one help me to fix this problem... if you need more detail about this please comment will share you.

***ADDITIONAL DETAIL***

- Messages are persist not transacted
- I have 5 consumers (each broker has own 5 real consumers and 2 forwarding consumers)
- The brokers and consumers not restarted during the test
- But the Publisher, start the process and publish the messages then it will be down, then after 15 mins its again start and publish
- The publisher connect the broker with DNS and the consumers are connected with comma separated TCP with failover:
- I am using postgres DB to store the messages the Journal and Store detail configuration is as follows

**Note:** the configuration is same for all the 3 brokers
*PersistenceFactory*

```
<persistenceFactory>
    <journalPersistenceAdapterFactory 
        journalLogFiles="10"
        journalLogFileSize="50MB"
        dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data"
        dataSource="#amq-postgres-ds"
        useDatabaseLock="false"
        createTablesOnStartup="false"/>
</persistenceFactory>
```

*The storage details*

```
<systemUsage>
    <systemUsage sendFailIfNoSpace="true">
        <memoryUsage>
            <memoryUsage limit="512 MB"/>
        </memoryUsage>
        <storeUsage>
            <storeUsage limit="3 GB"/>
        </storeUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="3 GB"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Also, why do you have a different JMSXGroupId for each message except the last one?  I'm not sure that's related to what's going on, but it seems strange at the least.

Comment: @Tim i am using ActiveMQ 5.9.0.

Comment: My use case is like this. The same 3000 JMSXGroupId is published in 15 mins cron. each cron the last 2 messages will publish with same JMSXGroupId

Comment: Observation: The messages mapped like forwardingConsumer->real consumer is struck up in the broker. The broker is not forward the messages to its mapped consumer (broker->realConsumer). this sound some issue in the network. But my brokers are connection with local LAN and there is no connection issues or reconnect attempt happening between them.

Comment: This absolutely doesn't sound like a networking issue, it sounds like a broker configuration problem.  My best guess is that this is probably related to how producers, consumers, and brokers connect to each other, so please update your post to tell us as much as possible about that.  Here are a few questions: How many consumers do you have?  3000, one per JMSXGroupId, so any given message can be consumed by only one consumer?  Where are those consumers and consumers located?  And does anything (brokers, producers, or consumers) get stopped/restarted during your test?

Comment: Also, are messages persistent, and if so what message store technology are you using?  And are you using transactions?

Comment: @Tim added the configuration details & answers

Comment: If you browse the queue via the web console, can you see the stuck messages?  And if not, if you restart the brokers, are the messages delivered successfully then?  There have been a number of bugs related to the cursors used to pull messages from the database not recognizing that there were undelivered messages; I think most or all of them have been resolved by 5.9.0, but is there any way you can run your test scenario against 5.10.0 to see if there's any change in behavior?  (If you can't upgrade your production brokers, that's fine, but maybe you could test with 5.10.0 on other machines.)

Comment: Yes Tim i can see the pending messages in browsers. To consume the messages we no need to re-start the brokers. Once we restart the daemons the pending messages will be consumed properly. Reason is the consumers are disclose from the broker such that the JMSXGroupId mapping is assigned to some other new consumers.

Comment: Are the stuck messages sitting on the broker where their intended consumer is?  That is, did the network of brokers route them to the correct broker, but that broker is failing to hand the message off to the consumer?  Or are they getting stuck on a broker that's not the one where the consumer is?

Comment: Yes, Both mentioned scenarios are happening. i seen the mapping cache using the help of jconsole. there we can find that the consumer'A'(consumerID) mapped to one message but the consumer'A' is not available in the browser. and some times the forwarding consumer is mapped to a message but the message is not received by the broker (fwd consumer).

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes the message gets to the broker where the correct consumer is connected and sometimes it doesn't?  Or are you saying that sometimes the consumer connects successfully and sometimes it doesn't?  I'm trying to help you figure out whether the problem is in broker-to-broker forwarding or in delivery to end consumers, so knowing whether or not the messages are dying on the correct broker may help you answer that question.

Comment: Also, in JConsole are you able to see if broker-to-broker subscriptions are being passed from the broker where the consumer connects to the other brokers (including the one where the producer for that messages is connected)?

Comment: @Tim i suspect the message group size is the issue. i have changed the message group size as 5 using the chachedMessageGroup and i publish 20 messages with the JMSXGroupId 1 to 20. the messages consumed successfully. But, if we publish the 20 messages with 3 different process at a time (each publish the same 20 messages) the messages start to struck up in the broker... Hope the message struck up starts when the pending messages count crosses the messageGroupSize. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: So I just noticed the following in the [Message Groups](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html) documentation: "With the default maxPageSize setting, large backlogs of messages destined for one group they can block receipt of messages to other groups if they don't all fit in memory."  That sounds a lot like what you're seeing, but as I understand it, that could only happen if one of your consumer was being assigned most of the message groups and if that consumer was running slowly (falling behind).  Is anything like that happening in your setup?

Comment: Also, what happens if you publish all messages as before - 3000 at a time per producer, using 2999 different JSMXGroupIDs, with each producer on a different broker - but have all of your consumers on the same broker?  The testing you described in your last comment sounds like it worked properly for 1 consumer but not for 3, so I'm wondering if 3 consumers will work properly if they're all on the same broker (even though the producers are on three separate brokers)...

Comment: And what's a message group size and a cachedMessageGroup, since you say you've changed those?  I don't see either one described in the documentation; can you point me to a reference?